# Installed entire font family, but only one appears

Tags: fonts, libreoffice, openoffice.org

I recently installed an entire family of fonts (Gill Sans for those interested) on my computer. When I open up OpenOffice to use them, however, I saw that in the drop-down font menu I only get to see Gill Sans Std, and unfortunately when I try and use that, it's actually Gill Sans Outline.

I can't see a way to choose between different fonts in a font family in OpenOffice - is there one?

I tried to use the fonts in gedit and could confirm that each individual font is present and usable.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OO, the menu is Format -> Character, from where you can pick out different styles.

Original answer was:

Have you updated your font cache?

```
sudo fc-cache -fv
```

And above all, what procedure do you used for installing fonts?

Comment: Just updated the cache, no change unfortunately. I simply double clicked on the .otf file and then clicked on the 'Install Font' button at the bottom right of the screen?

Comment: Did you follow that procedure for EACH .otf file?

Comment: Yep :) As I said, I can see all the fonts installed and usable in gedit.

Comment: It's seems to be a bug of OO, as you can read here: http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=65769
Don't know if it has already been reported.

Comment: I finally figured it out, using the final post from your link. The menu you have you use is Format -> Character, from where you can pick out different styles. I'm marking this as correct so that anyone else with this question can find it.

Comment: Great ... if I use it as a font in a document and open it in the other OO version I need to reset the styles ... not fun!